# How can I make the filter input take up the full width of the container in datatables with bootstrap 4?

Tags: datatables

I'm using datatables with the bootstrap 4 styling framework.  I'd like to make the filter input take up the full width of the page.  Currently I'm doing this by overriding the `dom` configuration to remove the pagination div, then applying styles to the `label` and `input` elements (code below) but this feels like a bit of a hack.  Is there a better way of doing it?

```
$("#table").dataTable({
  "dom":
    "frtip",
  ...
  "paging": false
});

#table_filter label {
  width: 100%;
}

#table_filter input {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: You can add markup within the `dom` - I've not used Bootstrap 4 yet but if there's a utility class then you can add it around the `f`, something along the lines of: `"<'row'<'some-utility-class'f>>rtip"` perhaps?

Comment: Good idea, at least I can override the default label and input css properties without relying on datatables giving its elements a particular id.  Thanks!